# Jetty addFilter with Spring Security and no web.xml

Tags: spring-security, jetty, spring-3, servlet-3.0

Normally I would have added `org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy` with a snippet like this to web.xml:

```
<filter>
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
    <filter-class>
        org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy
    </filter-class>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

But with Servlet 3.0 Container and Jetty, I've removed web.xml. I'm trying to add DelegatingFilterProxy to Jetty's launch with:

```
context.addFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.class, "/*", EnumSet.allOf(DispatcherType.class));
```

but I get error:

```
No bean named 'org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy-100555887' is defined
```

How am I supposed to create and add this filter?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

```
context.addFilter(new FilterHolder(new DelegatingFilterProxy("springSecurityFilterChain")), "/*", EnumSet.allOf(DispatcherType.class));
```

seems to be the correct syntax.